# What's the name of the song in Naruto that plays in episode 203 at 0:43?

Tags: naruto

What's the name of the song in Naruto that plays in episode 203 at 0:43?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8QwXScAUvNE

Answer (score 1):

The song is known as "Childhood Memories". It was not included in any of the [Naruto OST releases](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Music). However, there are many versions of it available on Youtube, such as [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hDfO4pkCcMM).